# Find expression with spaces in R

Tags: r, text, stringr

From a dataframe like this,

```
data_frame <- data.frame(com=c("chiffres au 31/12/2015","chiffre au 31/12/2008","chiffres au 31/12/08","xxx","abcd"))
```

I'd like to extract all expressions with the pattern "chiffres"+white_space+"au"+white_space+"dd/mm/yyyy"

I've tried with this pattern, but it doesn't work :

```
data_frame$date_plus_chiffre=str_extract(string=data_frame$com,
                               pattern="(chiffres)\s(au)\s([0-9]{2})(/)([0-9]{2})(/)([0-9]{4})")
```

How can I specify the white space in regular expression?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `?regex` states: `[:blank:] Blank characters: space and tab, and possibly other locale-dependent characters such as non-breaking space.`

Comment: You can also use `[:space:]` if you specifically want to detect spaces and not other blank characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a second \ before the \s, making it '\\s':

```
data_frame$date_plus_chiffre=str_extract(string=data_frame$com,
                                         pattern="(chiffres)\\s(au)\\s([0-9]{2})(/)([0-9]{2})(/)([0-9]{4})")
```