# R regular expression -- escape

Tags: r

Any idea why the R does not like the following regex?

```
df %>% filter(!grepl("/ (call|cfd|equity option|equity swap|put|swap|trs)\s*$/i", y))%>%
    filter(!grepl("/ (jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ?[CP]\s*$/i", y))
```

```
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""/ (call|cfd|equity option|equity swap|put|swap|trs)\s"
```

Comment: You just need two backslashes: `\\s`. R handles regular expressions a little different than what you'll find in a regex guide

Comment: or you use r"(...)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find expression with spaces in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169740/find-expression-with-spaces-in-r)